# How to create chat box using pusher with jquery/ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, pusher

view:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.4/pusher.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        Pusher.log = function(message) {
            if (window.console && window.console.log) 
            {
                window.console.log(message);
            }
        };
        var pusher = new Pusher('191dbef1780135573650');
        var channel = pusher.subscribe('my-channel');
        channel.bind('my_event', function(data){
            sendmessage(data);
        });
        function sendmessage(data)
        {
            var ses_id = <?php echo $this->session->userdata('client_id');?>;
            if(data.client_id == ses_id){
                html = '';
                html += '<li>'; 
                html += '<div class="author-thumb">'; 
                html += '<span>'+data.username+'</span>'; 
                html += '</div>'; 
                html += '<div class="notification-event">'; 
                html += '<span class="chat-message-item">'+data.message+'</span>';
                html += '<span class="notification-date"><time class="entry-date updated" datetime="2004-07-24T18:18">'+data.date+'</time></span>'; 
                html += '</div>'; 
                html += '</li>'; 
                $("html, body .chat_area").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
                $('#appendchat').append(html);
                $('#message').val("");
            }
            else
            {
                html = '';
                html += '<li>'; 
                html += '<div class="author-thumb">'; 
                html += '<span>'+data.username+'</span>';  
                html += '</div>'; 
                html += '<div class="notification-event">'; 
                html += '<span class="chat-message-item">'+data.message+'</span>'; 
                html += '<span class="notification-date"><time class="entry-date updated" datetime="2004-07-24T18:18">'+data.date+'</time></span>'; 
                html += '</div>'; 
                html += '</li>'; 
                $("html, body .chat_area").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 1000);
                $('#appendchat').append(html);
            }
        }

        $("#send").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            message = $('#message').val();
            $.ajax({
              url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>chatsend/",
              type: 'POST',
              data:{"message" : message},
              success:function()
              { 
              }    
            });
        }); 
    });
</script>
<div class="mCustomScrollbar chat_area" data-mcs-theme="dark">
    <ul class="notification-list chat-message chat-message-field" id="appendchat">
    </ul>
</div>
<form>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Type a message"></textarea>
    <div class="add-options-message">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary" id="send">Send</a>
    </div>
</form>
```

controller:

```
public function chatsend()
{
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Calcutta");
    $pusher = $this->ci_pusher->get_pusher();
    $data['message'] = $this->input->post('message');
    $data['date'] = date('H:i A');
    $data['id'] = $this->session->userdata('client_id');
    $data['username'] = $data['id'][0]['fname'].' '.$data['id'][0]['lname'];
    $event = $pusher->trigger('my-channel', 'my_event', $data);
}
```

In this code, I simply create chatbox using `Pusher` API. Now, the problem is that when I click on a particular user who is online or offline and wants to send them a message and when I click on `send` button it shows me nothing also when I remove further code inside in `send` button and simply `alert("hi")` then it also not working. So, How can I solve this problem? Please help me.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
$(document).on('click', '#send', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    message = $('#message').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>chatsend/",
        type: 'POST',
        data:{"message" : message},
        success:function(){}    
    });
});
```

and write out `sendmessage` function to outside of `$(document).ready`.